# Rails -- routing with wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Reports controller that I want to be able to hit with a number of different methods, params, and render types to extract whatever data I need in whatever format I want.  I have my route set up like this:

```
GET    /reports/:method(.:format)         reports#show
```

So I can hit it with a query like this:

```
/reports/stats_by_date.json?start_date=2013-10-01&end_date=2013-10-05
```

And my Reports#show method actually does the routing to the appropriate internal method.

Two questions:

1. I don't want to have to set up a route every time I set up a new report (I'm going to have a lot).  Is this the best way to handle a wildcard?
2. Assuming #1 is true, how do I perform a `GET` on the controller within my test cases?  I tried this with no luck:

`get :reports, :method => 'stats_by_date', :start_date => '2013-10-01', :end_date => '2013-10-05'`

Comment: why do you want to do it this way?  if you want to show a report for a range of dates, do it in the view for a given page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do this with routes, you would do this in the controller.

You'd have one route for `stats_by_date` with something like this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'reports/stats_by_date' => 'reports#stats_by_date'
```

And you would collect params within that action with something like this in your controller:

```
def stats_by_date
  start_date = params[:start_date]
  end_date   = params[:end_date]
  @stats     = Model.where('date >= ? AND date <= ?', start_date, end_date)
end
```